# Programming with Nokia Connectivity Cable Driver

Tags: driver, nokia

I want to program a software (with java or vb 6 or c++) which will send files to my nokia mobile phone. I want to use Nokia Connectivity Cable Driver for this purpose to send files to my mobile. But I cannot find any guide on the internet about how to do it. There is also no Nokia Connectivity cable driver developer documentation available. 
So please help me about from where should I start. (I know it is possible to send files using nokia connectivity cable driver  because Nokia Pc suite can do it using the same driver). 
[Actually I want to develop a software like Nokia PC suite. Please help me.]

Comment: If your Nokia mobile phone is connected via USB to your PC, you may be able to use Wireshark or a similar tool to sniff the traffic between mobile and PC.

Comment: But I want to communicate with the driver and send commands to the driver  to send files to my mobile. How can I do it?
And please explain how sniffing can help me?

Comment: Well, I thought of it as an alternative to using the driver as it would probably be a start on reverse engineering the protocol. My mistake